# SignalR failing to authenticate via cookies

Tags: authentication, .net-core, cookies, signalr

I have a couple of projects:

**Chat** - SignalR backend (ChatHub)
**Web** - MVC project that hosts clientside scripts, including those that make calls to the Chat project

I'm in the process of migrating from .NET Framework to .NET Core and am moving to SignalR for Core as part of this work. Cookie authentication is working correctly on the old version, but upon migrating to SignalR for Core, I appear to be having problems.

Cookie authentication is enabled in both projects. The Web project works fine and the Auth cookie is correctly recognised and used for authentication. The Chat project, however, is not correctly authenticated against the cookie, despite the cookie being included at least in the negotiate request:

[image]

When I make a call to the ChatHub, `Context.User.Identity.Name` is empty. The same call returns a populated name when run on the Web project. If I decorate the ChatHub with `[Authorize]`, the call fails with a 401.

[Here's a minimalistic repro project showing the issue](https://github.com/ajbeaven/SignalRCookieAuthenticationBug).

I assume the problem is related to the Authentication I have configured, or perhaps the cross-domain nature of the call?

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookie-authentication) is pretty unhelpful, and only says the following:

> In a browser-based app, cookie authentication allows your existing user credentials to automatically flow to SignalR connections. When using the browser client, no additional configuration is needed. If the user is logged in to your app, the SignalR connection automatically inherits this authentication.

This appears under some very basic configuration, which basically only calls `app.UseAuthentication()`. Alas, that configuration does not work for me.

How do I set Cookies authentication in SignalR for Core so it works across two projects?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that by default, the Data Protection system that ASP.NET Core uses to encrypt the auth ticket isolates apps from one another.

You need to [configure data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0) on each project you wish to share protected payloads to use the same key ring and app identifier:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("<appName>")
    // as well as the following calls if your projects are to be deployed on different machines
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("<blobUriWithSasToken>"))
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri("<keyIdentifier>"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - very helpful.  I had the same sort of thing; a web server issuing cookies via `HttpContext.SignInAsync` an a separate SignalR server consuming the cookies from the browser.  Needed to configure them with the same application name and the same one of the `PersistKeys` methods.  One small thing I'd add: to get the basic `AddDataProtection` extension methods, you need to be `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection`.